# Proper workflow with PyCharm and Python logging

Tags: python, intellij-idea

An aspect that I have not been able to get working is how to setup logging properly with PyCharm.

The guide that has taking me closest is [this](https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python/). However the issue still remains that I need to have `logging_setup.py` to be run before any other script is run.

Lets say I have a 2 file project `A.py` and `B.py` with contex:

```
A.py
import logging as log
log.info("IM IN A")

B.py
import logging as log
log.info("IM IN B")
```

How can I ensure that all logging configuration is run before I execute `A.py` or `B.py`?

> How are people setting up logging for projects in Python and PyCharm?

Comment: Just import `logging_setup` at the beginning of each file that you might run as an entry point.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to figure out how logging is done a little while ago, I actually didn't find Fang's pages too useful. This, http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/logging/, was a lot better. If you run your scripts in the same environment (e.g. production), just write a logging class that would specify logfile, format, etc. If you run those scripts in different environments, pass env as a parameter and read the name of the logfile from config file.